# Saving State After App Is Closed with Provider Package FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, state

What's the best way to save an activity page state with Flutter provider package? Currently, using the provider package and doing a restart or closing the app the page gets rebuilt and all the new widgets are removed. The state is saved on hot reload not hot restart. For example, the post created by a user on the news feed page is removed when I close the app or restart it.

Comment: Hello, `Providers` are not suitable for that. I suggest you to read about data persistance on flutter doc https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Answer (score 4):

So following the comment and reading the [flutter persistence cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence), I see three common possibilites:

- Persist data with SQLite
- Read and write files
- Store key-value data on disk

Each has different usecases, but I think the common case is to store a few objects as JSON. SQLite seems to me in simple cases an overkill and key-values do not offer enough flexibility. So I will focus on [reading and writing files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files).

Here comes an example. I use JSON code generation libraries as [described here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries).

The data object I read and write to disk is looks the following way:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

// json methods generated using code geneartion
// see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries
part 'easy_data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class EasyData {
    int counter;
    String data;

    EasyData(this.counter, this.data);

  // run the following command to generate json:
  // flutter pub run build_runner build
  factory EasyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$EasyDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$EasyDataToJson(this);
}
```

The Service to load the json from disk and save looks the following way:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import '../model/easy_data.dart';

class FileStorage with ChangeNotifier {
  EasyData loadedData;

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/app_data.json');
  }

  loadData() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();
      if (contents != null) {
        // parse json if file was saved before
        loadedData = EasyData.fromJson(json.decode(contents));
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } on FileSystemException catch (_) {
      // the file did not exist before
    } catch (e) {
      // error handling
      log(e);
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeData(EasyData data) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(data.toJson()));
  }
}
```

I used a [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example) for the service, because I want other services to be notified when the data is loaded from disk. The other Providers need to be declared with ChangeNotifierProxyProvider in main dart to use the information from the FileStorage Provider.

I hope it this was helpful.